# Access denied [403] when accessing site with BeautifulSoup python

Tags: python, python-requests, token, user-agent

I want to scrape https://www.jdsports.it/ using BeautifulSoup but I get access denied.

On my pc I don't get any problem accessing the site and I'm using the same user agent of the Python program but on the program the result is different, you can see the output below.

EDIT:
I think I need cookies to gain access to the site. How can I get them and use them to access the site with the python program to scrape it?

-The script works if I use "https://www.jdsports.com" that's the same site but with different region.

Thanks!

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.jdsports.it/'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
soup.encode('utf-8')

status = soup.findAll.get_text()
print (status)
```

The output is:

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

You don't have permission to access "http://www.jdsports.it/" on this server.<p>
Reference #18.35657b5c.1589627513.36921df8
</p></body>
</html>
>
```

python beautifulsoup user-agent cookies python-requests

Comment: BautifulSoup has nothing to do with it. You don't reach the part of your code where BS is involved, it is `requests.get` that fails to download the page.

Comment: The same script, with the same site but different region " https://www.jdsports.com/" works

Answer (score 0):

Suspected HTTP/2 at first, but wasn't able to get that working either. Perhaps you are more lucky, here's a HTTP/2 starting point:

```python3
import asyncio
import httpx
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
headers = {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36',
}
url = 'https://www.jdsports.it/'
async def f():
    client = httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True)
    r = await client.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)

asyncio.run(f())
```

(Tested both on Windows and Linux.) Could this have something to do with TLS1.2? That's where I'd look next, as `curl` works.

Comment: `curl`? The above is not a working example, as stated, it was an attempt at HTTP/2. You should look into SSL/TLS1.2, as also stated.